# Problema com scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu quero que quando eu clicar nos links, ele vá descendo no scroll. Consegui fazer isso e que ele deixe marcado *active* para cada um. Eu quase consegui fazer isso, ele fica *active* em quase todos menos no último. No último ele da o efeito de scroll mas não entra em *active*.

Trecho do menu:

```
 <div class="main-header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="menu-wrapper">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="logo-wrapper col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-8">

                                </div> <!-- /.logo-wrapper -->
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-4 main-menu text-right">
                                    <ul class="menu-first hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#services">O Fotógrafo</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#our-team">Últimos Eventos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#contact1">Area do Cliente</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-sm visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                                </div> <!-- /.main-menu -->
                            </div> <!-- /.row -->
                        </div> <!-- /#menu-wrapper -->
                        <div class="menu-responsive hidden-md hidden-lg">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#services">O Fotógrafo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#our-team">Últimos Eventos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact1">Area do Cliente</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- /.menu-responsive -->
                    </div> <!-- /.container -->
                </div> <!-- /.main-header -->
            </div> <!-- /.site-header -->
```

Em cada um dos itens que tenho no menus estão com o id certo, até mesmo o último:

```
<div class="content-section" id="services">
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    'use strict';


    /************** Toggle *********************/
    // Cache selectors
    var lastId,
        topMenu = $(".menu-first, .menu-responsive"),
        topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
        // All list items
        menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
          var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
          if (item.length) { return item; }
        });

    // Bind click handler to menu items
    // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
    menuItems.click(function(e){
      var href = $(this).attr("href"),
          offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
      $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
          scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, 450);
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       // Get container scroll position
       var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

       // Get id of current scroll item
       var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
         if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
           return this;
       });
       // Get the id of the current element
       cur = cur[cur.length-1];
       var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

       if (lastId !== id) {
           lastId = id;
           // Set/remove active class
           menuItems
             .parent().removeClass("active")
             .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
       }                   
    });



    $(window).scroll(function(){
         $('.main-header').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
     });



    $('a[href="#top"]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });


    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      slideshow: true,
      slideshowSpeed: 6000,  
      animation: "fade",
      directionNav: false,
    });


    $('.toggle-menu').click(function(){
        $('.menu-responsive').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });


    /************** LightBox *********************/
      $(function(){
        $('[data-rel="lightbox"]').lightbox();
      });


});
```

Comment: Amigo, faz uma força pra escrever melhor, ou é assim que você manda e-mail pro seu chefe ou cliente?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Melhor comentário o da revisão.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez foi sem maldade.